# Issue with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run the following code on my Raspberry Pi, but it is giving me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "video_capture_thresh.py", line 59, in 
>       main ()
>     File "video_capture_thresh.py", line 11, in main
>       crop = frame[180:320, 0:638]
>     TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
#cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

def main():
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        crop = frame[180:320, 0:638]
        crop2=cv2.cvtColor(crop,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        th,crop2 = cv2.threshold(crop2,0,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
        previous = cv2.GaussianBlur(crop2, (5,5),0)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(crop2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv2.rectangle(previous,(0,0),(638,140),(0,255,0),5) 
        i=0
        for cnt in contours:
            moments = cv2.moments(cnt)                          # Calculate moments
            if moments['m00']!=0:
                cx = int(moments['m10']/moments['m00'])         # cx = M10/M00
                cy = int(moments['m01']/moments['m00'])         # cy = M01/M00
                moment_area = moments['m00']                    # Contour area from moment
                contour_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)             # Contour area using in_built function
                perimeter = cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
                cv2.drawContours(previous, [cnt], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
                px = previous[cy,cx]
                if px == 255 :
                    i=i+1
                    cv2.circle(previous,(cx,cy),5,(0,0,255),-1)
        cv2.imshow("Previous",previous)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
main ()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check to make sure you actually read in OK before you do your processing

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        crop = frame[180:320, 0:638]
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `read`

> This is the most convenient method for reading video files or capturing data from decode and return the just grabbed frame. If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.

Check if the image is captured from camera well.

What kind of camera are you using?

Note that `cv2.VideoCapture` does not work with Raspi module camera, it just works with usb webcam.